# Where should I ask a question about processes?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on how to be compliant with all mail server's expectations, but it's not a technical question about how to configure the mail server itself.
It's more about **respecting best practices on that field**.

Where should I ask for this?

If more details needed, I actually asked the question in the wrong place: [How to run a legit mail server?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329337/how-to-run-a-legit-mail-server)

Comment: As soon as you ask for best practices, you've made the question opinionated. For more information, read [this M.SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based).

Comment: This *sort of* question is still common on Server Fault. It can be refactored to something like "how can I set up things so that I can configure the things I need so they work correctly". But how to run a mail server is a common FAQ which is already covered; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam for a start and perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624405/how-to-avoid-being-marked-as-spam-with-custom-mail-server as a remaining, closed as vaguely off-topic, question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I just add some info because I feel you don't understand my real issue here. I'm NOT trying to run a mail server, I already have one for years. I'm trying to be compliant with recent changes in the way Google and Microsoft deal with spam. If you think Server Fault is the place to ask for this, then I'll go there and try.

Comment: @gnat If you really dig into my case, you'll see I've really tried to find an answer by myself, to comply with recommended ways and I've also read a huge amount of documentation before even thinking to bother this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some people commented to try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), I've been there and found many questions similar or related.
So I've posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/970899/how-to-deal-with-microsoft-and-google-agressive-spam-policies).
I'm actually surprise those posts didn't show up in Google when I've searched at first.